# Spark Job in YARN - Executors are not executing the tasks for long time

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I can see the executors are not executing the tasks for long time from the Spark UI.

When i see the executors tab stderr, i can see the below logs.

```
6/02/04 05:30:56 INFO storage.MemoryStore: Block broadcast_91 of size 153016 dropped from memory (free 6665239401)
16/02/04 06:11:20 WARN hdfs.DFSClient: Slow ReadProcessor read fields took 31337ms (threshold=30000ms); ack: seqno: 1240 status: SUCCESS status: SUCCESS status: SUCCESS downstreamAckTimeNanos: 4835789, targets: [DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.25.36.18:1004,DS-f6e20cf7-0ccb-45aa-988f-f3310d5acf89,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.25.36.11:1004,DS-61ad0a2d-a6fd-402e-b0a1-61682d1755fb,DISK], DatanodeInfoWithStorage[10.25.36.5:1004,DS-c77503a2-0c7f-4b5c-8f4a-9c61cb4f18d7,DISK]]
```

I do not see any log for long time. i do not see error as well. It is keep on running..

Is anyone faced the same problem? how we can improve this?

**Update:**

It is actually took long time on `saveAsTextFile()` method.

Comment: Can you please update the code you have used?

Comment: can you specify the version of your Hadoop? it seems that this was an issue in version 2.5.0, but was fixed ages ago https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-7180

Comment: @GameOfThrows : I am using CDH 5.4.0 distribution.

Comment: do you coalesce your output before saveAtTextFile? It is natural for it to choke on that line, it does not necessarily mean that it is the saving process that is actually the problem.

Comment: @GameOfThrows : what if i want to merge the output files effectively?

Comment: you merge it using bash/command line, since every file is stored in partitions at the path folder, in Unix just do something like cat * > output.fileformat - coalesce is nice when you are doing testing, you get to see everything in 1 file, but it demands huge mem and should be avoided when your output file is expected to be large. (you easily hit GC overhead  with this function)

Comment: @GameOfThrows : I'm using `FileUtil.copyMerge` ,that is taking lot of time to merge 25 Million records.